# Loading NLog configuration from file on demand

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, nlog

I am using ASP NET 5 with MVC 6 and NLog. In the [NLog wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/) I saw that there is a convention regarding the configuration files so that they get automatically loaded and processed, however I can/know not how to do so on ASP NET 5.

I saw a tutorial explaining how to do some basic logging to a file [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1005242/Using-nLog-with-asp-net-vNext). The way they do it though appears to be less than optimal to me as they have to create a file or append some configurations to an existing one (which is fine by me) and then create a `class` to load the configurations to and then after that you have to manually create the targets based on the configuration and the `class` you are using(which is not).

Maybe am getting NLog configurations the wrong way but for what I read configuration is supposed to be loaded automatically, now I don't expect this to be so under ASP NET 5 since [they say support is practically none at the time being](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/493), but I was hoping I could still load the config files somehow on my application startup and initialize the NLog infrastructure directly from those files. Something like this

```
var nlogConfigSection = Configuration.Get<NLogProvidedClass>("configSection");
var nlogConfig = NLogConfig.FromProvidedClass(nlogConfigSection);
loggerFactory.AddNlog(new LogFactory(nlogConfig)
```

**OR**

```
var nLogConfig = NLogConfiguration.LoadFromFile("NLog.config")
loggerFactory.AddNlog(new LogFactory(nlogConfig)
```

So my question is: Is there a way to load the configuration file/section to the class/structure/whatever that NLog uses by default for initialization and initialize it from there?

Answer (score 0):

After opening an [issue](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1094) on github for a different reason [this comment](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1094#issuecomment-165595736) gave me an idea.There is an `XmlLoggingConfiguration` class that takes a `filePath` to a configuration file in the constructor and parses it into a valid `LoggingConfiguration` in this case a `XmlLoggingConfiguration`. So now what I have to do is just:

```
var config = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(configFile)
loggerFactory.AddNlog(new LogFactory(config)
```

and that's it, just what I was looking for.